# How do you make a fixed header with content underneath properly?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<header>` on my html page that is `position: fixed;` so that you can scroll down and the header stays there. There are two blocks (divs) under that. The header being fixed causes the first div to overlap the header, as you can see with inspect element and the background-color overlapping. What is the correct way to fix this? I have tried using margin-top but that does not solve the problem. More specifically, I was making a website similar to the [gmail about site](https://www.google.com/gmail/about/). I have used inspect element on their website and looked hard but I cannot seem to find how they do it. Here is a link to my jsfiddle if it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/e0mkLa3g/9/

Edit: My problem has been solved, but out of curiosity I still cannot figure out how that Gmail About Page mentioned above does it. They do not use margin-top at all in their body, but it is still not overlapped by the header.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12), inset 0 -1px 0 0 #dadce0;
}

.logo-text {
  height: min-content;
  float: left;
  line-height: 44px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

.create-account {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
}

.create-account:hover { 
  transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.create-account:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.sign-in {
  color: #666;
  float: right;
  border: none;
  line-height: 24px;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sign-in:hover {
  color: #111;
}

#block1 {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 500px;
}

#block2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <div class="logo-text">Cloudnotes</div>
        <button class="create-account">Create an Account</button>
        <a class="sign-in">Sign in</a>
    </header>
    <div id="block1">
      
    </div>
    <div id="block2">
    
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Try changing the background-color of the header, right now it is transparent. Also, try adding padding-top instead of margin-top to the first div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12), inset 0 -1px 0 0 #dadce0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

.logo-text {
  height: min-content;
  float: left;
  line-height: 44px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

.create-account {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
}

.create-account:hover { 
  transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.create-account:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.sign-in {
  color: #666;
  float: right;
  border: none;
  line-height: 24px;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sign-in:hover {
  color: #111;
}

#block1 {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin: 64px 0 0 0;
  height: 500px;
}

#block2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="logo-text">Cloudnotes</div>
        <button class="create-account">Create an Account</button>
        <a class="sign-in">Sign in</a>
    </header>
    <div id="block1">
      
    </div>
    <div id="block2">
    
    </div>
  </body>
```

Add to the Header: `Z-Index` + non-transparent `background-color`.
Add to the top Div (#block1) a `margin top` of at least the headers height.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. You don't need the Z index though, and the reason I had previously thought margin-top didn't work is because I had not put `top: 0;` for the header as you showed in your snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add `background-color: *color*;` to your `header` css because now it's `inherit` and it uses backgroud of elements under it.
You don't even need to use `z-index`.

Comment: true that you dont need z-index in that specific case. However you still need the margin top for the first div-element that willotherwise be cut by the header

Comment: This doesn't solve it completely because part of the div is still being covered up by the header. If I use margin-top then weird things happen (the header is shifted downwards), try it.

Comment: Your answer combined with tacoshy's fixed it. The margin-top issues were because I needed to put `top: 0;` for the header.